# Delete empty directories Synology NAS Shell

Tags: shell, nas, synology

I try to delete my empty directories on my Synology NAS (DS415+).

I tried:

```
find . -type d | xargs rmdir
```

But the problem is that I have directroies with spaces in the names like 
"hello (2012)". And the argument "-empty" is not supported on the Synology Kernels.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you know any programming languages? The Synology package center offers a number of interpreters including Python, Perl, PHP, Ruby, and some Java flavors. You could write a script in one of those languages accessing a system's module that may be able to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Yes i know a little bit Python but it should also work with a Shell script shouldn't it?  
I tried this but then it haves a problem with the `-type d`  
`#!/bin/sh  
find . -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file  
do  
printf "\"%s\0\"\n" "$file"  
done`  
But I install Bash now I will write back later thanks @AMR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that I misunderstood you, but it seems that you are working with a **POSIX** shell.

You can do it with `awk` (`gawk`). As far as each empty directory contains only 2 files by default (`.` and `..`), you can use `[ $(wc -l <<< $(ls -as $DIR)) -ne 2 ]` as folder emptiness condition.

```
$ find . -type d | awk '{print "[ $(wc -l <<< $(ls -a \"" $i "\")) -eq 2 ] && rm -rf \"" $0 "\""}'
```

This is what output I get out of tested directory:

```
[ $(wc -l <<< $(ls -a ".")) -eq 2 ] && rm -rf "."
[ $(wc -l <<< $(ls -a "./skda  askd ()")) -eq 2 ] && rm -rf "./skda  askd ()"
[ $(wc -l <<< $(ls -a "./skda  askd () 2")) -eq 2 ] && rm -rf "./skda  askd () 2"
```

Now all you got to do is to pipe these commands to your interpreter. At my test directory this worked cleanly.

Comment: I will try it now thank you very much @theoden

Comment: @Beni, not a problem. The question was clear.

Comment: I think i have to install Bash... on Ubuntu it works @theoden

Comment: For everyone who haves the same problem under this [link](http://www.synology-wiki.de/index.php/Bash) you can see how to install bash on the Synology NAS after that you can use the solution from theoden.

Answer (score 2):

[`xargs(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) does not split at spaces but at newlines.

Unless you have directories with newlines in their name, this will work.

```
find . -type d -exec rmdir {} +

  =>  rmdir ./dir1 ./dir1/subdir1 ./dir1/subdir2 ./dir2 ...
```

But we delete the parents before the childs...  So instead, we want:

```
find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} +

  =>  rmdir ./dir1/subdir1 ./dir1/subdir2 ./dir1 ./dir2 ...
```